# magento reset password email via php code

Tags: customer, email, email-templates, password

i want to create reset password link and mail it to customer using php code what have i to write to do this could not figure out ?..

i wrote below code in my custom page but it not works:

```
$email='abc@gmail.com';

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
$newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $customer->_getHelper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
echo $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Comment: i have made custom layout page for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a rest link by email

```
$email='abc@gmail.com';

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                    ->loadByEmail($email);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
```

Comment: no i just want to create reset password link after that magento will take care :
i write below code in custom page but it is not working


$email='abc@gmail.com';

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);
$newResetPasswordLinkToken =  $customer->_getHelper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
echo $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();

Comment: thanks its working, but how can i get password reset link like
http://abc.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=165&token=12cc766b2768f4fad7fd09b333943818

or i want to use different email template is that possible

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, can you explain what your tying to accomplish?

Comment: but what if want to reset password of one of admins , how can i use above code to work ?..

Comment: Take a look at `orgotpasswordAction()` in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php

Comment: We put this code in my custom file test.php when we run this file at that time we found wrong wrong url.  On button URL is 'xyz.com/test.php/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=0001'  Any one help me how to remove file name from link.

Answer (score 0):

could you explain your use-case in more detail and where you put your code? Otherwise it is hard to help.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I was actually asking for more information, it is not clear what the the question is about.

Comment: The answers section is reserved for answers. Do not ask questions in the answer section. [Take a tour of SE](http://magento.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how things should work in here.

Comment: "Use comments to ask for more information or clarify a question or answer." => got it

"You can always comment on your own questions and answers. Once you earn 50 reputation, you can comment on anybody's post." => So I couldn't ask, my reputation is 29 :( So it's better to wait and not ask for more information?